# ESC/POS printer cuts paper before printing all content in buffer

Tags: escpos

I am writing code (in C#) that prints receipts to an ESCPOS printer, and currently using an EPSON TM20II for testing. I am printing directly on a COM port on Linux and via an emulated COM port over USB on Windows. Although I am able to print any kind of comment normally, I am having an issue with cutting the paper.

More specifically, if I send a cut paper command (`GS V 0`) after the rest of the content and send the entire stream of bytes to the port, the printer cuts the paper before printing the last lines of content.

At first I thought it was a timing issue, so I tried sending the rest of the content, and then waiting for a small amount of time before sending the Cut command, but to no avail.

This is a sample of the code I use and the contents of the buffer I am sending to the printer which fails to cut the paper at the proper location.

```cs
printer.Reset();
printer.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.Center).PrintTextLine(" 1234567890 ");
printer.SetTextSize(TextSize.Quadruple).PrintTextLine(" 1234567890 ");
printer.CutPaper();
printer.Print();
```

produces the following (hex) output sent to the printer:

```
1B-40-1B-74-0F-1B-61-01-20-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39-30-20-0D-0A-1B-21-30-20-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39-30-20-0D-0A-1D-56-00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kalhspera!

There is a distance between the cutting mechanism and the thermal printhead.  So before you send the cut paper command, you must feed the paper a bit.  One solution is to send a few linefeeds before sending the cut paper command.